# "identifier is undefined" when calling functions defined in class (separate cpp file) from main

Tags: c++, function

I'm very new to c++ and to my understanding if i include the header file which is where the functions are defined, i should be able to call the functions from main? I have tried to add static or public before the functions but nothing seemed to change.

//heres my main

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "myfile1.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    function1();
    function2();
}
```

//my myfile1 header

```
#ifndef myfile1_h  
#define myfile1_h

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myClass{
    void function1();

    void function2();
};

#endif
```

//my myfile1.ccp

```
#include "myfile1.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myClass{
    void function1() {

    }

    void function2() {
    }
}
```

Comment: `myfile1.h` doesn't mention `function1` or `function2`. In `main.cpp`, those names are never declared.

Comment: my bad i forgot to change those

Comment: `function1` and `function2` are members of `myClass`, but you are calling them as if they were a regular non-member functions. You need something like `myClass obj; obj.function1();` Besides, they are private members of the class; `main` won't have access to them.

Comment: is it possible for me to just add static to them like u can do in java?

Comment: i dont really want to create an object of this class

Comment: Also definitions should rather look like `    void myClass:function1() {`

Comment: If you don't want them to be class members, why do you bother with `myClass` at all? Just declare them at file scope, same as `main` itself.

Comment: I havent learned about them yet. do you declare them in the main.cpp? I was told thats a very bad idea

Comment: @Icarus _"I was told thats a very bad idea"_ That's a [_cargo cult_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). If you don't need a class scope for a function, don't use one, period. Other than in java you don't need a class for everything in c++. Also disambiguation can be achieved by using namespaces.

Comment: @Icarus But why don't you [precise your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64094250/edit) in that direction of what you really want to know? Burying this information in comments isn't very helpful for giving you a good answer about your concerns.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Im really not sure about that lol. this question is now solved but so many more questions have sprung up in the process. It's probably not appropriate to ask them all here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions are in the myClass in myfile1. You must create object from this class, and you can use functions where in the this class. My English skills are not good but you must do this:

```cpp
int main(void){
    myClass myClassObject;
    myClassObject.function1();
    myClassObject.function2();
}
```

If you dont want create object from this class, you can do that :

myfile1.h:

```cpp
#ifndef myfile1_h  
#define myfile1_h

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void function1();
void function2();

#endif
```

myfile1.cpp:

```cpp
#include "myfile1.h"

void function1(){
    cout<<"function1"<<endl;
}

void function2(){
    cout<<"function2"<<endl;
}
```

and main:

```cpp
#include "myfile1.cpp"

int main(){
    function1();
    function2();


    return 0;
}
```

If you want this functions with class, you can do it for good case:
myfile1.h

```cpp
#ifndef myfile1_h  
#define myfile1_h

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myClass{
    public: // If you want access these functions, you must use public tag.
            // If you dont use any tag, it will be private, because default tag is private.
    void function1();
    void function2();
};


#endif
```

myfile1.cpp

```cpp
#include "myfile1.h"

void myClass::function1(){
    cout<<"function1";
}

void myClass::function2(){
    cout<<"function2";
}
```

main:

```cpp
#include "myfile1.h"

int main(){
    myClass myClassObject;
    myClassObject.function1();
    myClassObject.function2();
    
    return 0;
}
```

What is your compiler or editor? If you compile that codes from terminal, you must compile it like this:
`g++ main.cpp myfile1.cpp`

My English skills are not good. But I tried to explain.

Comment: i see you declared the function 1 and function 2 without creating a class. say if I want to declare them within a class, should i declare them like "void myclass::function1(){}"?

Comment: Yes, this is good case. i will edit my answer for you now.